# Pairwise distance in very large datasets

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I have an array that is about [5000000 x 6] and I need to select only the points (rows) that are at a certain a distance from each other.

The ideia should be:

> Start new_array with first row from data array
>
> Compare new_array with the second row from data array
>
> If pdist between they are > tol, append row to new_array
>
> Compare new_array with the third row from data array
>
> and so on...

One problem is RAM size. I cant compare all rows at once even in pdist.

So I've been thinking in split the dataset in smaller ones, but then i dont know how to retrieve the index information for the rows in dataset.

I've tried scipy cdist, scipy euclidean, sklearn euclidean_distances, sklearn paired_distances and the below code is the fastest i could get. At first it is fast but after 40k loops it becomes really slow.

```
xyTotal=np.random.random([5000000,6])
tol=0.5
for i,z in enumerate(xyTotal):
    if (pdist(np.vstack([np.array(ng),z]))>tol).all():
        ng.append(z)
```

Any suggestions for this problem?

**EDIT**

```
ktree = BallTree(xyTotal, leaf_size=40,metric='euclidean')
btsem=[]
for i,j in enumerate(xyTotal):
    ktree.query_radius(j.reshape(1,-1),r=tol, return_distance=True)
    if (ktree.query_radius(j.reshape(1,-1),r=tol, count_only=True))==1:
        btsem.append(j)
```

This is fast but I'm only picking outliers. When i get to points that are near to anothers (i.e. in a little cluster) I don't know hot to pick only one point and leave the others, since i will get the same metrics for all points in the cluster (they all have the same distance to each other)

Answer (score 1):

The computation is slow because **the complexity of your algorithm is quadratic**: `O(k * n * n)` where n is `len(xyTotal)` and `k` is the probability of the condition being true. Thus, assuming `k=0.1` and `n=5000000`, the running time will be huge (likely hours of computation).

Hopefully, you can write a better implementation running in `O(n * log(n))` time. However, this is tricky to implement. You need to add your `ng` points in a **k-d tree** and then you can search the **nearest neighbor** and check the distance with the current point is greater than `tol`.

Note that you can find Python modules implementing k-d trees and the SciPy documentation provides [an example of implementation](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/KDTree_example.html) written in pure Python (so likely not very efficient).

Comment: Hello, Jérôme. I have already tried something similar using sklearn NearestNeighbors.

`outroneigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2)

filtered=[xyTotal[0]]

for i,j in enumerate(xyTotal):

    outroneigh.fit(np.vstack([filtered,j]))

    if outroneigh.kneighbors(j.reshape(1,-1),return_distance=True)[0][0,1]>tol:

        print(i)

        filtered.append(j)`

Problem is that for achieving the same answer as the other method, i need to keep fitting an appended array. This fitting is much slower than pdist.

Comment: It is not `append` the problem here but the `np.vstack` that rebuild a full new array from all the past values. You do not need that. Actually, the `append` is not needed too. You can just pre-allocate a big array, assign the cells and slice the good part if you want to use a Numpy array. Note that, on CPython lists, I think `append` should run in amortized `O(1)`. You should focus on the complexity first, and then on optimizations/vectorization.

Comment: I see your point and agree.But i can't figure it out how to not use appends or rebuild arrays, since i have to test points from one array against points from another array and concatenate if condition. Also pdist only works with ndarrays, so i need to build an array to pass to pdist. But if you are telling me to do one fit in entire data array with KDTree, I tried it once with NearestNeighbors.I tried to get the distances of each point to all, but the result was not the same.Doing it I can be sure about outlier points, which i want, but it gets messy when I have close points, which i MAY want.